# Dos sitios web en uno mismo Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente problema que no se como solucionarlo.

Proyecto en Laravel 8.

Dispongo de dos dominios:
prueba.es
prueba2.es

Cada uno, tiene una vista, Modelo y controladores diferentes.

En mi fichero route he intentando hacer esto.

```
Route::get('/', function (Request $request, $pag = 'index') {
    $url = explode('/' ,$request->server('DOCUMENT_ROOT'));
    $domainFolder = end($url);
    return view($domainFolder.'/index');
});
```

Hasta aqui todo correcto me retorna la vista de cada dominio.

Pero si quiero pasar por el controlador de cada uno de los dominios no se como hacerlo.

¿ Como se podria hacer esto ?, no se si lo que hice es optimo o buena practica.

Comment: La solución no va en la pregunta, para eso tienes la zona de respuestas, por favor edita y corrige

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion

Route::group(['domain' =>

Comprueba el dominio y te lleva a la ruta correspondientes

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'prueba.es'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```

Comment: explica porque funciona tu solucion.